# polidea BLE decode characteristic value in react native

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, base64, bluetooth-lowenergy

i'm trying to decode the packages i recive from BLE but i don't have any luck. If you have any ideea and you can help me i would appreciate. Here is a sample of base64 that i recive:

```
A0IARQ==
AcgAyQ==
Av0BAA==
BGQEbA==
```

i should get speed, battery voltage, option byte and odo

```
OPCODE APP  Bluetooth
START_PACK, OPCODE, LENGTH, D0, D1 . . DN, CHECKSUM         (START_PACK = 0x55)
OPCODE
0x01 – Speed
0x02 – Battery Voltage
0x03 – Option Byte
[7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0] bit 7 = Zero Start, bit 6 = Km/Mile, bit 5 = Unlock/Lock, bit 4 = Light On/Off
0x04 – ODO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the  Polidea/react-native-ble-plx library it seems that the data from reading the characteristic is returned in base64. So as bytes array your values would be:

```
AcgAyQ== is [1, 200, 0, 201]
Av0BAA== is [2, 253, 1, 0]
A0IARQ== is [3, 66, 0, 69]
BGQEbA== is [4, 100, 4, 108]
```

This looks like the first byte is the OpCode and the last is the checksum. I'll assume the bytes in between are value in little endian.

I experimented with some code:

```js
import toUint8Array from 'urlb64touint8array';
import { Buffer } from 'buffer'

var speed_bytes = toUint8Array('AcgAyQ==');
var battery_bytes = toUint8Array('Av0BAA==');
var option_bytes = toUint8Array('A0IARQ==');
var odo_bytes = toUint8Array('BGQEbA==');

var speed = Buffer(speed_bytes).readInt16LE(1) / 10;
var battery = Buffer(battery_bytes).readInt16LE(1) / 10;
var options = (Buffer(option_bytes).readInt16LE(1) >>> 0).toString(2)
var odo = Buffer(odo_bytes).readInt16LE(1) / 10;

console.log('Processing speed: [' + speed_bytes + '] ' + speed);
console.log('Processing battery: [' + battery_bytes + '] ' + battery);
console.log('Processing option: [' + option_bytes + '] ' + options);
console.log('Processing odo: [' + odo_bytes + '] ' + odo);
```

Which gave the following output:

```
Processing speed: [1,200,0,201] 20 
Processing battery: [2,253,1,0] 50.9 
Processing option: [3,66,0,69] 1000010 
Processing odo: [4,100,4,108] 112.4
```

Comment: now when i send the package back i need to calculate on base64 this package`START_PACK, OPCODESEND, LENGTH, D0, CHECKSUM                  (START_PACK = 0x55)
OPCODESEND
0x02 – Speed Limit
 D0 – 1 is 6Km/k, 2 is 12Km/h, 3 is 20Km/h, 4 is 25Km/h, 5 No speed Limit
`